# Primitive Technical Error (141) when querying the flight_destinations endpoint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amadeus

I'm a student creating a demo app using your test API, and am getting the following error  when querying the flight destination API (eg. https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/flight-destinations?origin=PAR&maxPrice=200)

I don't get any error when querying the same location using the flight offers search API, so it's not an issue with my key/secret, and the location is definitely included in the limited test API dataset.

I'm using the ruby gem (https://github.com/amadeus4dev/amadeus-ruby) but faced the same issue testing the API on postman.

Any help appreciated!

```
    {
        "errors": [
            {
                "status": 500,
                "code": 141,
                "title": "SYSTEM ERROR HAS OCCURRED",
                "detail": "Primitive technical error"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue with the flight-deals endpoint. I submitted a request to Amadeus support and got the following reply:

*Unfortunately we are currently having some issues with this API in the test environment. Our technical team is currently looking for a solution, in the meantime if you need to use this endpoint, please move your app to the production environment where the API will work as expected....in this environment you will receive a free amount of transactions each month just like in test*

I did try going over to a production environment and I'm not getting technical errors (500's) any more. It does require signing up for payment in case you go beyond the free tier of request volumes. Not clear when they will have the test environment up and running.